# Smooth dynamic images on Apple Watch (30fps)

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit

Based on

http://www.raywenderlich.com/94672/watchkit-faq and
http://forums.toucharcade.com/showthread.php?t=261237&p=3542936

There's a limit of about 10 FPS for dynamic images, and 30fps wtih pre-rendered images.

The touch arcade link shows a smooth animation of a paceship flying through 3D space. Did they have to pre-render *each* image before hand?

How can I dynamically generate images at a reasonable FPS?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like everything is pre-rendered. It reminds me of the old 90's video games like Megarace where they used the exact same technique.

You first pre-render the background and have it loop.

Then pre-render objects in the scene (like that spike object) zooming in.

Then you pre-render all permutations of the spaceship depending on its location in the view. I would split the screen into a grid of maybe 6x6, so you'll have a total of 36 pre-rendered perspectives of the ship.

Then layer everything onto the view.

Comment: Damn. So if I have a lot of variables in my gameplay, I'd have *a lot* of pictures to pre-render..

Comment: Yep. You'll need to prerender each object and them layer them onto the view. Or you can wait until WWDC on June 8. There are a lot of hints of a native Watch SDK.